# Importar componentes según una condición react

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

estoy creando un hamburguer menu con react que carga un icono diferente para cada ruta, la idea es que el usuario pueda ingresar un string con el nombre del icono y un componente  se encargue de importar individualmente el icono y lo muestre. Estoy utilizando la libreria react-icons. React icons tiene 10 familias de iconos disponibles, trate importando todo para utilizar pero mi archivo App.js queda con un peso superor al 10MB.

¿Como puedo importar un componente según un string?
Algo asi.

```
import React from 'react'
import { MdErrorOutline } from 'react-icons/md'


const Icon = ({name, className}) => {

  let selectedIcon = require('react-icons/md' + name)


return (
    <div className="icon__wrapper">
        {selectedIcon({className})}
    </div>
)
}

export default Icon
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo podrias lograr asi(no lo he probado):

```
import React from 'react'
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/md'


const Icon = ({name}) => ( // quite className pero si lo necesitas lo agregas
    <div className="icon__wrapper">
        {ReactIcons[name]}
    </div>
)

export default Icon
```

y ya usearias el componente Icon asi:

`<Icon name="MdDone" /> // aqui pasarias el nombre del icono`

(el detalle es que de todas maneras estarias importanto todos los iconos)

Comment: Si lo hice de esa manera y funciona, pero carga 10 MB de iconos adicionales que no voy a usar.

Comment: o que tal si creas un archivo donde importes solo los iconos que necesitas(uno por uno) y ya importas ese nuevo archivo en este archivo donde creas los Iconos.

Comment: Para ese caso te recomiendo icomoon, https://icomoon.io/ suerte y comenta si te sirve. Básicamente agregas los iconos que necesitas y descargas, luego solo llamas a esa librería que descargas, así pesaría bastante menos.